# Property not defined on the instance but references during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using VueJS 2.5.16, in a sfc way with TypeScript and vue-class-component

My BookingTable.Vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="refresh-button" v-on:click="refresh()"><img src="../assets/Data-Synchronize.png"></button>
        <table>
            <tr v-bind:key="booking.id" v-for="booking in bookings">
               [...]
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
     class Booking {
         Id : number = 0;
         StartTime : string = '';
         EndTime : string = '';
         EnergyConsumed : number = 0;
         User : number = 0;
         Parking : number = 0;
         Plug : number = 0;
         Charging : boolean = false;
         Cancellation : string = '';
     }

    export default class BookingTable extends Vue {
         bookings : any;

       [Other properties and methods]
 
</script>
```

And this is the Warning that VueJS is throwing :

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "bookings" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I already searched through both stack overflow and github issues section but I could not undertand where my mistake was. So if someone can explain it to me, i'll be very grateful :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) is what is bound in the template scope.  It doesn't look like you have `data` defined anywhere.  You can even see this in the [Microsoft Vue TypeScript example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/src/components/Hello.vue).

Use this:

```
export default class BookingTable extends Vue {
    data(): {
        return {
            bookings: [];
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively it looks like you can use decorators to declare properties as well per this example in the same repository from above: [HelloDecorator.vue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/src/components/HelloDecorator.vue)

Comment: Thank you so much ! It was voluntary for me to use the "class" way, and using the decorators solved my problem !